# Ubuntu install after windows wipe

Tags: system-installation

So my mom's computer was so overrun with viruses and spyware/malware etc. That I told her the best thing to do was to wipe the system and start over. I ran the recovery program from BIOS and found after it wiped the hard drive that it had no partition for recovery.

I decided the next best thing to buying new $200 software was to install Ubuntu since she only uses the computer for email and internet surfing. I downloaded the Ubuntu `.iso` file and burned it to a DVD. I booted the computer from the disc and chose the option to erase the current OS and install Ubuntu over it.

Every time I try to run the installer it crashes. It keeps telling me that there may be something wrong with the hard disk but I'm not sure what. It's a new computer, not even a year old.

Is there something else I should do to try and install Ubuntu?

I'm new to this so any suggestions would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

When you go into the installer again, on the screen that it asks you to "Erase everything and Install Ubuntu", select the very last option instead that says like..."Something else".

Select **all the partitions** in the list one-by-one, click the *Delete* button and in the empty space click the *New* partition button.

Select the created partition and click *Change* and set to `mount at /` with `Use as` set to `ext4`

If you have enough ram you dont need a swap space and you can click *Install* and ignore the warning. Otherwise, go make a swap space, then continue.

Oh but if your drive is > 2 TB then it's probably set to GPT and this could potentially be the root of your HD issue.  In which case...you need to erase the partition table and reset it on that same screen with the partitions.  Then you reboot, relaunch the installer and continue where you left off.